# Can we extend the theta function $\theta(z)$ to p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, theta-functions, adeles

Let $\theta(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2}$ with $q = e^{2\pi i n z}$.  Can we extend the theta function to $p$-adic arguments?  Here's an example:

$$ \theta( 1 + p^k) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2} e^{2\pi i n^2 (1 + p^k)} = \theta(1) $$

In my textbook they define a rather unusual upper half plane $\mathbb{H} \simeq SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \backslash SL(2, \mathbb{R})/SO(2, \mathbb{R}) $ but there is also the adelic way to define the same object:
$$\mathbb{H} \simeq SL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \backslash SL(2, \mathbb{A})/SO(2, \mathbb{A}) $$
There is even a more basic question of what elements of $SO(2, \mathbb{A})$ even look like.  Perhaps these are rotations of the circle $\{x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: It is not about extending $\theta(z)$ to $p$-adic arguments, but to make it a function on $SL$ or $GL(2,\mathbb{Q})$ with $F(\gamma) =(ci+d)^{-k} \theta(\gamma.i)$. Because $f \in M_{k}(\Gamma_0(4))$ then $F$ is really a function on $\Gamma_0(4) \backslash GL(2, \mathbb{R})/SO(2, \mathbb{R})$. The adelization is to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(\gamma_n)$ converges when $\gamma_n \in GL(2,\mathbb{Q})$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}_v$ (for $v = \infty$ it is obvious, for $v = p$ you need to use  left $\Gamma_0(4)$ invariance) thus $F$ is well-defined as a function on $GL(2,\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: @reuns Yes.  When we first learn theta functions, it is a function of $\mathbb{H}$ or $\Gamma_0(4) \backslash \mathbb{H}$.  Now it has been extended to $2 \times 2$ matrix arguments: $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and in fact $SL(2, \mathbb{A})$.

Comment: And the fact $\theta(z) = (2iz)^{-1/2} \theta(-1/4z)$ instead of $\theta(z) =\pm (2z)^{-1/2} \theta(-1/4z)$ means you need to use double covers of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ (symplectic groups..) so it is easier to look first at modular forms of integer weight.

Comment: @reuns once I have more coffee perhaps I can improve the statement of the question.  I'd encourage you to post an answer.  If it is more convient use $\theta(z)^2$ or $\theta(z)^4$.

Comment: What I wrote is in any text introducing automorphic representations. $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the stabilizer of $i$.

Comment: @Lubin What do you mean ? The [Tate curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_curve) allowing to translate  "complex elliptic curve = complex torus" to certain $p$-adic elliptic curves ? In that case I don't see how it is related to adelization of modular forms.

Comment: Sorry, @reuns, I was confusing several more-or-less unrelated things. I’m deleting my comment.